# Элемент формы, увеличивающий или уменьшающий число на 1

Tags: c#

Как называется элемент Windows формы, где можно увеличивать или уменьшать число на 1? Вот так выглядит.

[image: элемент формы]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это элемент управления [NumericUpDown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/729xt55s.aspx). Вообще список всех контролов (на русском языке), с которым можно сверяться в случае необходимости есть здесь: [элементы управления для использования в формах Windows Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/3xdhey7w.aspx).